# error: Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I created a micro and a user form on Excel VBA, when I double-click the Excel file and try to run the macro it gave me the error:

error: Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

The form name is `MainForm` and the code in `ThisWorkbook` is as below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    MainForm.Show
'MainForm is a Userform that former person created
End Sub
```

Should I use Visible property?... How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run it in debug mode - step by step to see WHERE the error actually occurs.

Comment: What is ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False ? What are u trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Shai Rado it hides all instances of excel so that ultimately only the userform will be showing.

Comment: @Barry Wang I believe that the issue may somehow be raised when you are trying to show or hide the userform. I can

Comment: What's the value of Y4? If VBA is implicitly casting it to a string to make the `=""` comparison, you'd get a *type mismatch* error if the cell contains an error value, e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#REF!`.

Comment: Exactly which line raises the error?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Application` is just a reference to the host... it's the same as doing just `Application` - except `Application.Visible = False` would be a less expensive call, because it doesn't need to access `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: This question currently doesn't have enough information to be answered, if you're wondering why it's downvoted. Please [edit] the question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue may somehow be raised when you are trying to show or hide the userform. I cant get the error to replicate in my own code, but I believe I have had this happen before. Creating the form as an object may solve the issue:

```
Dim oForm as MainForm
Set oForm = New MainForm

oForm.Show
```

Also, I am not sure why the MainForm would already be open when you are opening the workbook that contains it (for your else statement). You shouldnt need to do hide the userform unless it is somehow persisting between workbook opening and closing events (this would be a matter of what you are using the code for).

Comment: Declaring it `As Object` makes all later calls to it be late-bound / resolved at run-time, which means you don't get intellisense for `.Show` so your code will happily compile if you type `.Snow` instead... Why not declare it `As MainForm`?

Comment: That would definitely be better. I completely forgot that once the MainForm object exists within the scope of the document it can the be used as an object type. I edited the code to fix this.

Comment: FWIW I think the question is unanswerable as it stands - for all we know there could be code in the form's `Activate` handler that causes the run-time error... OP doesn't tell us where the error is happening, so all we can do is speculate. I agree that it would be (much) better practice to work off a new instance of the form rather than off the *default instance*, so have an upvote for that... but I don't think it will change anything as far as OP's specific problem is concerned.